# How to create a new object from an existing one?

Tags: javascript

This doesn't work, and I have no idea how to fix it

```
function bar() {...}

function foo() {
    this = new bar();

    this.newfunction = function() {...};
    this.newvalue = "foobar";
}

var foobar = new foo();
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to inherit from `bar`? Then you can borrow its constructor and all its own properties using `call` (or `apply`):

```
function bar() {...}

function foo() {
    bar.call(this);
    this.newfunction = function() {...};
    this.newvalue = "foobar";
}

var foobar = new foo();
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `this` to represent another object.

```
function bar() {...}

function foo() {
    var bar = new bar();

    bar.newfunction = function() {...};
    bar.newvalue = "foobar";
}

var foobar = new foo();
```

Comment: 'bar' is not a constructor

Comment: @defunct, What were you trying to do?